# Retrieve hashtags, how to output the result?

Tags: r, output

I am trying to retrieve hashtag from 16077 of tweets
For example I would like to have the list of all the hashtags in below tweets

```
df<-c("Good #food to be had in #Sibu. Here are some leads #VisitSarawak #VMY2014", "Spore white card, well aren't you a sight for sore eyes! Thanks ! #finallygoinghome","Low cost air travel will drive intra-Asian integration; experiencing trend myself this week on and #fingerscrossed")

library(stringr)
hashtag<-str_extract_all(df, "#\\S+")
> hashtag
[[1]]
[1] "#food"         "#Sibu."        "#VisitSarawak" "#VMY2014"     

[[2]]
[1] "#finallygoinghome"

[[3]]
[1] "#fingerscrossed"
```

How can I export the results into csv file? I tried with below code but resulting in error

```
write.csv(hashtag,file='C:/R_working_directory/hashtag.csv',row.names=F)


Error in data.frame(character(0), character(0), character(0), character(0),  : 
 arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1, 4, 2, 6, 3, 5, 7, 9, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have in `hashtag`?

Comment: @David, I have added some examples of the tweets I have

Comment: I didn't get any error

Comment: Probably because the sample I showed here is very small.

Answer (score 1):

You could build a data frame out of the list and then output that with `write.csv`:

```
dat <- data.frame(id=rep(seq(length(hashtag)), lapply(hashtag, length)),
                  hashtag=unlist(hashtag))
dat
#   id           hashtag
# 1  1             #food
# 2  1            #Sibu.
# 3  1     #VisitSarawak
# 4  1          #VMY2014
# 5  2 #finallygoinghome
# 6  3   #fingerscrossed
write.csv(dat, file='C:/R_working_directory/hashtag.csv',row.names=F)
```